# what's wrong with my program,so only the letter i can't be counted?

Tags: c, for-loop, scope, c-strings, variable-declaration

So here, I want to solve one of the problems in my basic programming class. So, the problem is, we should count the vowel letter and print how many A/a, I/i, U/u, E/e, and O,o letters are in a string. In this case, I used an ASCII for checking the letter. All the programs run so well but I found one problem. My program cannot count the I/i letter. There always be counted zero although I input an "I" letter. Can you help me fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    int len, a = 0, i = 0, u = 0, e = 0, o = 0;
    char str[150];
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &str);
    len = strlen(str);

    for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++){
        if(str[i] == 65 || str[i] == 97){
            a++;
            continue;
        }
        if(str[i] == 73 || str[i] == 105){
            i++;
            continue;
        } 
        if(str[i] == 85 || str[i] == 117){
            u++;
            continue;
        } 
        if(str[i] == 69 || str[i] == 101){
            e++;
            continue;
        } 
        if(str[i] == 79 || str[i] == 111){
            o++;
            continue;
        } 
    }

    printf("A/a : %d\n", a);
    printf("I/i : %d\n", i);
    printf("E/e : %d\n", e);
    printf("U/u : %d\n", u);
    printf("O/o : %d\n", o);

}
```

Comment: You might consider using character literals like `'A'` instead of magic numbers. Makes it much more obvious what's being tested without having to look at an ASCII chart. `switch(str[i]) { ... }` might look a little nicer too.

Comment: There's no need for `scanf` here.  (There's never a need for `scanf`, but that's a different discussion!). Your problem is not at all inherently line oriented; you only ever care about one character at a time.  You ought to use a loop like `int c;                                                                   while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' ){`. (The check against `\n` is only necessary to duplicate the current functionality, although it seems unlikely that you actually want to abort after one line of data.)

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing the variable `i` in your `for` loop.  Change the loop index to `j`, for example, and it'll work.

A few other things:

1. Instead of using magic numbers such as `65` and `97` I'd suggest using `A` and `a`.
2. Using `else if` would be preferable than many `if` statements and `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", &str);
```

is incorrect. For example the expression `&str` has the type `char( * )[150]` instead of the expected argument of the type `char *`.

You should write

```
scanf("%149[^\n]", str);
```

In this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++){
```

the declared variable `i` hides the variable with the same name declared before the for loop.

Also there is no sense to use the condition `i <= len` instead of `i < len`.

Though using the function `strlen` is redundant.

And do not use magic numbers like for example `65`. This makes the program unreadable and moreover the program will not work if the system supports the EBCDIC character table.

Instead of the if statements with the continue statement it will be much better to use a `switch` statement.

Your program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int a = 0, i = 0, u = 0, e = 0, o = 0;
    char str[150];

    scanf( "%149[^\n]", str );

    for ( const char *p = str; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        switch ( *p )
        {
        case 'a': case 'A':    
            a++;
            break;

        case 'i': case 'I':
            i++;
            break;

        case 'u': case 'U': 
            u++;
            break;

        case 'e': case 'E':
            e++;
            break;

        case 'o': case 'O':
            o++;
            break;;
        } 
    }

    printf( "A/a : %d\n", a );
    printf( "I/i : %d\n", i );
    printf( "E/e : %d\n", e );
    printf( "U/u : %d\n", u );
    printf( "O/o : %d\n", o );
}
```

To make the program more safer you could also check whether the input of a string was successful as for example

```
    if ( scanf( "%149[^\n]", str ) == 1 )
    {
        for ( const char *p = str; *p != '\0'; ++p )
        {
        //...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're just starting out, the cupboard where all the tools (knowledge & techniques) is pretty bare. You wind up writing awkward code (often using copy/paste) to try to wrestle a problem to the ground. This is normal.

As you gain experience, you learn the value of *re-using* code that you've written (making it smarter, not bulkier). This is where using *functions* arises. A capable function can be written, tested and then re-used for similar but different purposes.

Other answers give good guidance on using *tokens* ('A') instead of *magic numbers* (65) that may be wrong and that cause readers to reach for their "decryption" tables to check those numbers. The `scanf()` format specifier isn't good, and there's no protection from buffer overrun. Using 'continue' instead of `if/else` is unconventional, and I don't like the way the conventional ascending sequence A->E->I->O->U has been shuffled in the code. Why make things more challenging (and prone to bugs)?

The code below may appear intimidating, but the beauty of C code is that you can examine one line at a time and come to understand its purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cntThese( char *valid, char *str, int cnts[] ) {
    // Passed a string of 'paired' characters,
    // a sample string
    // and array to use as accumulators.
    // When a character is interesting
    // pointer arithmetic yields the index of the appropriate accumulator.
    char *p;

    for( int i = 0; str[i]; i++ )
        if( (p = strchr( valid, str[i] )) != NULL )
            cnts[ (p - valid) >> 1 ]++;
}

int main() {
    char *str = "{Twas BRILLIG <<<and>>> { [[the]] (ugly) slithy toves} }";
    int i, cnt[ 32 ]; // big enough accumulator array 

    char *vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu"; // count the vowels (case insensitive)

    memset( cnt, 0, sizeof cnt ); // zero the counters
    cntThese( vowels, str, cnt );

    for( i = 0; i < strlen(vowels)/2; i++ )
        printf( "%2.2s - %d times\n", vowels+i+i, cnt[i] );

    char *braces = "{}()[]<>"; // count the braces and brackets

    memset( cnt, 0, sizeof cnt ); // zero the counters
    cntThese( braces, str, cnt );

    for( i = 0; i < strlen(braces)/2; i++ )
        printf( "%2.2s - %d times\n", braces+i+i, cnt[i]/2 );

    return 0;
}
```

```
Aa - 2 times
Ee - 2 times
Ii - 3 times
Oo - 1 times
Uu - 1 times
{} - 2 times
() - 1 times
[] - 2 times
<> - 3 times
```

You can imagine how easy it would be, now, to count the occurrences of each of the 26 letters of the alphabet, or whatever purpose you have in mind.